# sending data using HttpWebRequest with a login page 

Tags: c#, authentication, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send data for this page by using HttpWebRequest class :

```
www.stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/_FormsWizard/CreateForm.asp
```

but I faced a problem with the login authentication . 
heres my code :

```
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    string postData = "ctlMessageID=" + 348;
    postData += ("&ctlUserID=" + 7);
    postData += ("&ctlTitle=" + 7);
    postData += ("&ctlEmail=" + "rrawhi@gmail.com");
    postData += ("&ctlIsSystem=" + 0);
    postData += ("&ctlFormBody=");
    postData += ("&ctlEnableCaptcha=");
    postData += ("&ctlEmailAttachedFiles=");
    postData += ("&ctlMailingList=");
    postData += ("&ctlCommentaryTitle=" + 1);
    postData += ("&ctlIsActive=" + 2);
    postData += ("&ctlCommentaryPersonID=" + 6);
    postData += ("&ctlOrderKey=");
    postData += ("&Commentary_TextControl_html=" + "aaaaaaaaaaaa");
    postData += ("&controlValue4=" + 666666);
    postData += ("&ctlLanguageID=" + 1);
    postData += ("&ctlAya=" + 349);
    postData += ("&PathInfo=" + "dbsFramed, dbsFramed");
    postData += ("&Caller=" + "rawhi");
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/_FormsWizard/CreateForm.asp");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();
```

And this is the Login page :

```
www.stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/Login.asp
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of authentication is being used to log you in? It doesnt look like you are supplying any credentials?
Also, postData should be a StringBuilder. concatenating lots of strings like that is bad practice.

Comment: let alone the bad practice , my problem is the Login page is actually not the real login page but instead it redirect to another webpage `PostLogin.asp` which in it's turn redirect to the main page . I've tried to use the cookies stuff but that didn't work for me also.

Comment: If you're posting across multiple pages you will need to keep the cookies stored in CookieContainer and add them to the request every time you do a send.

Comment: this helped me solve my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First off, it looks like you aren't actually sending the request.  To send the POST request to the server you need to request the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
string responseContent = null;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
    //get the text content of the response, if needed
    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Also, it looks like the page you are posting to is looking for an established and authenticated Session.  Try posting credentials to the login page (http://stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/Login.asp) first.  Set HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer to a new CookieContainer() instance.  Then, do another post to the CreateForm.asp page but be sure to set the new HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer object to use the same instance of the CookieContainer you used when you did a POST to the login page.  Then the cookies received from the login page will be sent to the CreateForm.asp page and the session will be "maintained" from the server's perspective.  For instance:

```
CookieContainer m_cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/Login.asp");
...

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
HttpWebRequest formRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stage1.darotools.com/Quran.v1.admin/_FormsWizard/CreateForm.asp");
formRequest.CookieContainer = myRequest.CookieContainer;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
    //get the text content of the response, if needed
    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Comment: I've tried this also but every time I require the CreatForm page it redirect me into the login page which contains only the login form and the actual login page is be handled in PostLogin.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); // domain is not needed in case of forms authentication
```

If this doesn't work you can authenticate user on login page and passing CookieContainer there and then reuse that CookieContainer when requesting needed page.

Comment: I could not believe it was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this links will help you:

[webrequest login session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166432/c-webrequest-login-session)

[keep session id over httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453560/c-keep-session-id-over-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things that could be going on here

Try setting some credentials

```
myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// if we have a proxy set its creds as well
if( myRequest.Proxy != null )
{
     myRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}
```

And make sure you're setting a UserAgent and Accpet settings as well.

```
myRequest.UserAgent = "Foo";
myRequest.Accept = "*/*";
```

If you add these I don't think you will have any issues.